# Redirect Web2py requests to apache server

Tags: apache, web2py

I am using web2py to run some application in the server, and i have also websites created with php running on the same server under apache. Is there a way to redirect requests for web2py to apache based on the domain name used.
I have little information about apache so i appreciate some explanation.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Name based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) for Apache.  Besides, redirects based on some specific conditions can be implemented with `mod_rewrite`.